# Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(\frac{9}{4} \right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} \right)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

may someone show how to compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(\frac{9}{4} \right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

According to W|A it's e, but I don't know even how to start...

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clearly,
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n^2}<
\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n^2}<2\,\mathrm{e}^n,
$$
and therefore
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}<
\left(\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n}\le 2^{1/n}\mathrm{e}
$$
which implies that
$$
\mathrm{e}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n}\le \lim_{n\to\infty}2^{1/n}\mathrm{e}=\mathrm{e}.
$$
Hence the limit of $\,\left(\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right)^{1/n},\,\,$ as $\,n\to\infty$, exists and it is equal to e.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

By Taylor series we have

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2}\sim_\infty e^n
$$

but $$\frac 9 4<e$$
hence
$$\left(\frac{9}{4} \right)^n=_\infty o(e^n)$$
hence
$$\left(\left(\frac{9}{4} \right)^n+\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\sim_\infty e$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: Yes it is great answer cause of using basics of Calculus appropriately. +1